# Where to find the Evolution contacts files

Tags: data-recovery, email, evolution

I recently re-ïnstalled Ubuntu after having problems with the former  Ubuntu-installation. To my surprise Mozilla Thunderbird was now installed as email program, instead of my former Evolution email program.

All my former contactdata has disappeared.

So I decided to install Evolution again. But my contactdata is still not found yet.
Is there a chance that the data files from the former Evolution installation still exist on the disk?

If so, where do I find them to import?
Or with which program can I recover them?

Comment: How did you reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on usb-memory, and reḯnstalled it from there.

Comment: Well if you erased the disk so unless you had backups somewhere all your data is gone

Comment: I did not expect that the installation would destroy all files, just the systemfiles. I still have an old bu-file from Evolution. And then I have to rebuild the missing data again. Thanks for your quick response

Comment: Why would you expect that blasting away the contents of a drive by installing an os would preserve everything but system files? There is even a warning in the installer that says something along the lines "This will erase the contents of the disk. Are you sure?"

Comment: I think you are right. I saved all my personal files as a backup, except for the most recent contactfiles for the reason I mentioned before. For now I know enough. Thanks

Comment: The installer offers you several options - one wipes everything (formats the partition), another does not format and tries to keep existing data. You have not specified which option you chose...though reading between the lines, I suspect you perhaps have chosen the former and wiped everything.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to import former contact list from the operating system: the disk was formatted when installing new version of Ubuntu.

You can recover files in the whole disk at before the new ubuntu installation if you think it worths, by using this software: EaseUS Data Recovery www.easeus.com (for windows). Just install EaseUS Data Recovery on a windows machine, extract the hard disk with ubuntu, then plug the hard disk with ubuntu to the windows machine as external drive (or secondary hard disk).